# How to plot only max values for yerrorbars in Gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I have this plot where I show the average values and the standard deviation. The problem is that there is a high +/- error on some lines and I would like to show only the max values for the standard deviation. So the plot can be more clear. Now I am using `linespoints` and `yerrorbars` and the plot looks like below:

[image]

As you can see the orange and green lines vary a lot. I would like to show only the max values for them so the plot becomes more clear. The script that I am using is below:

```
plot \
 t=0 "throughput-vs-networkbuffer-500K-8reducers-all.csv"         every 30 u (t==0?(t0=timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt),t=1):NaN, timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt)-t0):(column(8))             skip 2 notitle "no pre-agg"         with linespoints lc rgb '#E02F44' lt 1 lw 1.0 ps 0.7 pt 2 pi 30 axis x1y1 \
,t=0 "throughput-vs-networkbuffer-500K-8reducers-all.csv"         every 30 u (t==0?(t0=timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt),t=1):NaN, timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt)-t0):(column(8)):(column(9)) skip 2 title   "no pre-agg"         with yerrorbars  lc rgb '#E02F44' lt 1 lw 1.0 ps 0.7 pt 2 pi 30 axis x1y1 \
,t=0 "netBuffer-20K-200K-20K-8local-8global-onephase-all.csv"     every 28 u (t==0?(t0=timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt),t=1):NaN, timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt)-t0):(column(2))             skip 2 notitle "local mini-batch"   with linespoints lc rgb '#008000' lt 1 lw 1.0 ps 0.6 pt 6 pi 28 axis x1y1 \
,t=0 "netBuffer-20K-200K-20K-8local-8global-onephase-all.csv"     every 28 u (t==0?(t0=timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt),t=1):NaN, timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt)-t0):(column(2)):(column(3)) skip 2 title   "local mini-batch"   with yerrorbars  lc rgb '#008000' lt 1 lw 1.0 ps 0.6 pt 6 pi 28 axis x1y1 \
,t=0 "netBuffer-20K-200K-20K-8local-8global-twophase-all.csv"     every 26 u (t==0?(t0=timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt),t=1):NaN, timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt)-t0):(column(2))             skip 2 notitle "local agg 2-phases" with linespoints lc rgb '#FF780A' lt 1 lw 1.0 ps 0.6 pt 8 pi 26 axis x1y1 \
,t=0 "netBuffer-20K-200K-20K-8local-8global-twophase-all.csv"     every 26 u (t==0?(t0=timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt),t=1):NaN, timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt)-t0):(column(2)):(column(3)) skip 2 title   "local agg 2-phases" with yerrorbars  lc rgb '#FF780A' lt 1 lw 1.0 ps 0.6 pt 8 pi 26 axis x1y1 \
,t=0 "netBuffer-vs-latency-20K-200K-20K-8adcom-8reducers-all.csv" every 24 u (t==0?(t0=timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt),t=1):NaN, timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt)-t0):(column(4))             skip 2 notitle "AdCom pre-agg"      with linespoints lc rgb '#3274D9' lt 1 lw 1.0 ps 0.6 pt 5 pi 24 axis x1y1 \
,t=0 "netBuffer-vs-latency-20K-200K-20K-8adcom-8reducers-all.csv" every 24 u (t==0?(t0=timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt),t=1):NaN, timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt)-t0):(column(4)):(column(3)) skip 2 title   "AdCom pre-agg"      with yerrorbars  lc rgb '#3274D9' lt 1 lw 1.0 ps 0.6 pt 5 pi 24 axis x1y1 \
```

I improved it by adding 4 columns where the third is only the average and the fourth is the average + the standard deviation:

```
X:(column(2)):(column(2)):(column(2) + column(3))
```

However, if there is a way more elegant to do it I appreciate any help!

Comment: I don't see a simplification what you call a "hack", that's what `with yerrorbars` does with 4 columns.

Comment: yes. you are right. it is another form of calling `yerrorbars`. However, I would like to have only the max values. I think using `(column(2) + column(3)` is already the solution.... I don't know if there are alternatives....

Comment: What do you mean with only the max values? No symbol at min, no line from min to avg, no (error)symbol at avg, a line from avg to max and an error symbol at max?

Comment: the line of the average and the error from the average to the max values. Hide the min values

Comment: with `yerrorbars` you will also get a error-symbol at avg. If you want to avoid this, you could use `with vectors` for the vertical line from avg to max together `with points` for the error-symbol at max, but this not really short and "elegant".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a minimal example for half an error bar using `with vectors` and `set style arrow`.
Although, I'm not sure whether it is "experimentally acceptable" to just display "half" an error bar.

**Code:**

```
### "half" yerrorbars
reset session

$Data <<EOD
# x  y       yerr
1    0.10    0.05
2    0.20    0.10
3    0.45    0.21
4    0.67    0.28
5    0.44    0.11
EOD

unset key
set xrange[0:6]

set style arrow 1 size 0.1,90 lc "red"

plot $Data u 1:2 w lp pt 7, \
     ''    u 1:2:(0):3 w vectors as 1 
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]